# Turining An HTML <td> into a link ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, html.actionlink

I'd like to be able to turn rows of an html table into links to controllers.
I figured something like

```
<td onclick="<%:Html.ActionLink("", "Index", new {id=item.user_id}) %>">
```

I'm using MVC 2

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just put a hyperlink inside the TD, then you are not reliant on JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td onclick="window.location='<%:Url.Action("Index", new {id=item.user_id}) %>'">
```

The `onclick` attribute accepts some javascript code to execute. If you simply give it a URL, javascript doesn't know what to do with that.

In the snippet above, you're setting the `window.location` property to the desired URL. This causes the browser to go there.

**EDIT:** I also just realized that you were using the `Html.ActionLink()` method which actually generates an `<a href=""></a>` tag in your code. You'd be better off using the `Url.Action()` method, which actually generates a URL.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that to work because it complains that the name is null or undefined, but I tried this
onclick="window.location.href='/Controller/Method/<%:item.user_id%>'" and it liked it

Comment: I just edited my answer while you were posting that comment. If you use the new edited snippet, it will work. I would avoid "hard coding" your links like that. Using the Url.Action() method will do you better down the road.

Comment: That's perfect. I knew there had to be a better solution.

Comment: Well if you like the answer, you should click the little checkbox just to the left of it to mark it as ACCEPTED. *cough cough*